# Write a batch file that installs EXE shortcut on computer remotely

Tags: batch-file, scripting, installation, exe, ini

I am writing a script to install a program remotely on requested computers. Only problem is that the file we invoke to install the application is actually a shortcut that points to an .exe and an .ini so it can install with specific parameters. Is there a way I can run the shortcut from the batch file so that it points to both file and installs on the users computer with parameters already set?

Comment: shortcurts are just .lnk files. you can copy those around at will...

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?
xcopy "source" "destination" Example: xcopy E:\fileC:\Users\user\destination

Comment: Not exactly. The .bat file reads a txt file with a bunch of computer names and runs the shortcut file to install the program on their C drive.